# What's the relative path to a user's profile?

Tags: 7, users, uri

I've created a [clickable block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552893/how-to-create-a-clickable-block) with Views and rewrote the fields with HTML like this:

```
<a href="user"> some divs... </a>
```

Clicking the block should refer the logged-in user to his/her profile. As the code mentions, I'm using `user` as relative link, but a problem occurs when the user clicks the link when he/she is already visiting his/her profile: the link is then turned into `mysite/user/user` instead of `mysite/user`.

Using `/user` doesn't work either, because it redirects the user to `localhost/user` instead of `localhost/mysite/user`.

What's the correct way to construct a path that takes into account either being relative or the `$base_path`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no, and can not be always correct relative path.

Relative path is relative, and there is no infinite amount of paths to user profile, to be in the same relation with each and every path in your system. There cannot be. What you need is to **properly generate an absolute path instead**.

So instead of the code you are using, use Drupal's built-in link generator, [`l()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7):

```
<?php print l('some divs', 'user'); ?>
```

or, if above is not feasible, [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7):

```
<a href="<?php print url('user'); ?>"> some divs... </a>
```

Comment: Your answer looked promising, but apparently Views can't evaluate the PHP in your code. I'm currently using the code in a "Global: Custom text" field.

Comment: @Jeroen as a matter of fact views **can** evaluate PHP code. In tpl files. Just move your wrapper to tpl, where it probably belongs, and you are good to go. Anyway, my answer answers your question from the moment of posting. If you will change question's meaning and make this answer irrelevant, I'll go away and have a beer, and delete this answer when I'm back ;) Of course you can always ask a more specific question about URLs in views fields.

Comment: I've tested your answer and the link to the user's profile worked correctly this time, although the view wasn't displayed as it should be (a result of my lack of experience with these kind of things). Would you mind taking a look at my question about this at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112711/how-to-wrap-a-whole-views-block-in-a-tpl-file?

Comment: Yes! I've got it fixed now that I know how to write a template for the view. Let me give you another upvote for sparing me a lot of lost hours.

Answer (score 0):

if you create it with 'user/[uid]' it will be added to the current url.

Create it with a / in front to make it start at your domain, use '/user/[uid]'.

@Gregory: he is using a [token] so it's no code. More like a block in views or something.

To clarify my comment:

`<a href="/user">profile</a>` or /user in views as a link is always user specific. It brings anonymous users to the register/login page and logged in users to their own page. No need to put [uid] or !1 or something behind it.

Comment: /user brings you to your own profile too you know.

Comment: I guess the uid here comes from an input, we're not talking about the user's own profile... are we ?

Comment: Then just make a link to /user as @Marcel suggests :)

Comment: @GregoryKapustin: I did that, but the problem is still there. When a user clicks the link when he/she is already visiting his/her profile, he/she is redirected to `mysite/user/user`.

Comment: Event with <a href="/user">profile</a> ?

Comment: @GregoryKapustin: That simply redirects the user to `localhost/user` whether or not he/she is visiting his/her profile.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/user/!1"> ... </a>
```

will do the trick.